# Load properties for spring context from command-line

Tags: java, spring, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I want to write a spring command line program that is initialized with a property file which is passed as command line parameter. How can that be done?

Starting class:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    String configFilename = args[0];
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "classpath:/context/applicationContext.xml");
    MyBean bean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class); 
    bean.getStarted();
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="CONFIGFILENAME" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

How do I get the config file name over from my main method to the actual spring context so that I can load the correct environment dependent properties?

Comment: You could possibly use a JVM argument instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598217/how-do-i-read-jvm-arguments-in-the-spring-applicationcontext-xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, you could better set a system property for properties file location

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("location", args[0]);
```

Then in applicationContext.xml file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${location}" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.