# CondtionalBean in depending on jvm arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, javabeans, jvm-arguments

I can use `Condtional Bean` in connection with `application.properties`. However, I consider is it possible to do the same thing, but using jvm arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ralph posted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598363/1967021), you can use Spring EL expressions to refer to `systemProperties` bean and thus accessing JVM args.

E.g. refer as `#{systemProperties.test}` for `-Dtest="hallo welt"`