# Java Spring batch access command line arguments in XML and Java Annotation config

Tags: spring, spring-batch, java-annotations

How can I get the command line arguments in a xml configuration file with spring?

With property file I can write this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:///my.property" /> 

    <bean id="mybean">
      <property name="prop1" ref="#{jobParameters['value.from.property']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mybean2">
      <property name="prop1" ref="#{jobParameters['value2.from.property']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mybean3">
      <property name="prop1" ref="#{jobParameters['value3.from.property']}" />
    </bean>
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

But how can I explain Spring to get the values from command line arguments instead of property file specified in property-placeholder?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read JVM arguments in the Spring applicationContext.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598217/how-do-i-read-jvm-arguments-in-the-spring-applicationcontext-xml)

Comment: How are you launching your application?

Comment: I pass the application context xml and add -Dvalue.from.property=abc

Answer (score 0):

To read from property file use

```
<property name="prop1" value="${value.from.property}" />
```

To read from Job Parameter use

```
<property name="prop1" value="#{jobParameters['value.from.jobParameter']}" />
```