How to pass list in SQL query - Spring Batch Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is
Before posting the question - I went through below URLS, but it was clear enough to me

Using SpringBatch JdbcCursorItemReader with List as NamedParameters
How to set list of parameters on prepared statement? etc

In my case, I must need to use SQL query with IN clause. I'm reading from relational DB and write it into CSV file using Spring Batch XML config approach.
I am getting below error
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Executing query; SQL [SELECT * FROM emp.employee where age in (?)]; Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.translateSqlException(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:226) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:133) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:453) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1358) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1714) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:398) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:231) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:162) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.ListPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ListPreparedStatementSetter.java:60) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at com.example.setter.EmployeePsSetter.setValues(EmployeePsSetter.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:126) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

Below is the complete code
Employee.java
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "create")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {
    private Long empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    private String email;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return empId + "," + firstName + "," + lastName + "," + age + "," + email;
    }
}

EmployeeMapper.java
public class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> {

    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee result = new Employee();
        result.setEmpId(rs.getLong("empId"));
        result.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        result.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        result.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
        result.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        return result;
    }
}

xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598217/how-do-i-read-jvm-arguments-in-the-spring-applicationcontext-xml -->
    <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="false" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="employeeJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="employeeItemReader"
                             writer="cvsFileItemWriter"
                             commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="Password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeSetter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.ListPreparedStatementSetter">
        <property name="parameters">
            <list>
                <value>22</value>
                <value>44</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="sql" value="SELECT * FROM emp.employee where age in (?)"/>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.example.mapper.EmployeeMapper"/>
        </property>
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="employeeSetter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:cvs/employee.csv"/>
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"/>

        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value=","/>
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="empId, firstName, lastName, age, email"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>

MainApp.java
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-batch-context.xml");

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("employeeJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Exit Status : "+ execution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Job ExamResult failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

EmployeeSetter
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.ListPreparedStatementSetter;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Setter
public class EmployeePsSetter extends ListPreparedStatementSetter {

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        String params = new StringBuilder("'").append("22").append("'").append(",'").append("44").append(",").toString();
        ps.setObject(1, params);
        super.setValues(ps);
    }
}


Show 'EmployeePsSetter.java' line 18 where 'setValues' apparently has 2 values when code is only expecting 1...

@JanNielsen - Thats where the confusion is, could you please let me know what needs to be changed? I've added that class too here
